# GUI works but the console's (CTRL-ALT-F1-F6) "don't"

Tags: 12.04, console, tty

I just upgraded to 12.04 and have just noticed that the `tty` sessions tty1-tty6 accessed via <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> have a distorted graphics output whilst the GUI <kbd>F7</kbd> and terminal windows within the GUI work fine.

It would seem like some incorrect resolution setting, but I do not want to risk loosing all screen output by messing up the settings.

What settings should I be looking at?

Grateful for assistance.

Comment: What do you mean by "distorted"?

Comment: What kind of graphics card are you using and which driver? (For example Nvidia cards this can be the proprietary ``nvidia`` driver or ``nouveau``.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the lastest drivers for your graphics card? If you haven't, then follow this steps:

- Click on the **Dash**
- Search for **Additional** and click **Additional Drivers**
- Wait a bit, and you'll see a list with all the compatible drivers for your computer.
- Check if your graphics card name appears at that list, select the entry for it (I usually select the "post-release" entry, or the one that has [Recommended]) and click Activate. After a while, you'll have to restart your computer.

Maybe this will work to you, be sure to have all the updated drivers before of doing anything! Hope it works to you and tell us soon.