# new monitor has 1920x1080 but only show 1366x768

Tags: 12.04, resolution, screen, monitor, external-monitor

I just got a new 32" monitor with 1920x1080 (Viore)

But my Ubuntu is only showing resolutions up to 1366x768

Even thought the laptop (ultrabook) itself (Samsung) has 1600x900 on it's own monitor.

I turned off the Samsung screen so as to just have the external screen but that didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the lastest drivers for your graphics card? If you haven't, then follow this steps:

- Click on the **Dash**
- Search for **Additional** and click **Additional Drivers**
- Wait a bit, and you'll see a list with all the compatible drivers for your computer.
- Check if your graphics card name appears at that list, select the entry for it (I usually select the "post-release" entry, or the one that has [Recommended]) and click Activate. After a while, you'll have to restart your computer.

Maybe this will work to you, be sure to have all the updated drivers before of doing anything! Hope it works to you and tell us soon.

(Sorry for the duplicated answer, the original by me can be find [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/188085/12-04-gui-works-but-the-consoles-ctrl-alt-f1-f6-dont/189486#189486).)